# What is the downsides of using vanilla js in this angular directive using youtube Iframe Api?

Tags: angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive

I instinctly know this is wrong, but how to do this otherwise. It is not example that reflects something more complex what I am trying to do.

First tried to inject $document & $window. But $document did not have access to createElement method.

Nother thought is that I can use this type of logic if I wrap some of it in $scope.apply();

full code plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XueCvhwB6kOecBWYgmjJ?p=preview)

```
app.directive('videoPlayButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFunction
  };

  function linkFunction(scope, el, att, controller) {

    var player; // need this available for button eventlistenter

    // Invoke on documet.ready(see bottom)
    ready(loadPlayerFunction);


    ///// Directive Methods

    // Inject iframe_ap if not available & configure/reference Iframe player 
    function loadPlayerFunction() {

      if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {

        // inject youtube iframe_apiscript as 1st script tage in the header 
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      }

      // onYouTubeIframeAPIReady: youtube iframe APi method
      // Allows to config & reference your iframe to the api
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        loadPlayer();
      }

      // Configure & check if ready(& worked)


      function loadPlayer() {
        player = new YT.Player('youtube-video', {
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // Check if everything is functioning

      function onPlayerReady() {
        console.log("hey Im ready");
        //do whatever you want here. Like, player.playVideo();

      }

      function onPlayerStateChange() {
        console.log("my state changed");
      }


    } // loadPlayerFunction


    // Logic for detached basic play/pause button
    var playButton = document.querySelector('#playTheVideo');
    console.log('playButton', playButton)

    playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var state = player.getPlayerState();
      if(state === 1) {
         player.pauseVideo();
      } else {
        player.playVideo(); 
      }

    });

    // Non jQuery on document.ready
    // Source: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready
    function ready(fn) {
      if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
        fn();
      } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: why a  -1 without a comment? would be helpful for any feedback:)

Answer (score 1):

Using document.createElement is pretty common in Angular (as is stuff like querySelector when trying to get an element by class name); depending on what you're doing, it often gets wrapped in an angular.element call:

```
var elem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'));
// which I think is equivalent too...
var elem = angular.element('<script></script>');
```

So maybe something like this:

```
var theSource = 'http://something';
var tag = '<script src="' + theSource + '"></script>';
// Or this might go too...
// var tag = document.createElement ( 'script' );
// tag.src = theSource;
var elem = angular.element(tag);
var firstScriptTag = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]);
firstScriptTag.prepend(elem); // or append, depending
```

Comment: Gotcha thx. I have used that convention before. Thanks for the reminder. Forgot.  I should say the code that I am using works. Just not sure in this case why use angular.element if it is working. Besides getting away to getting jqlite interface on the element.

Comment: Yah I realize your code was working, but you mentioned you felt somehow it was wrong. The above example can make it feel a little more angular-ish maybe, and it's usually how I see it get done inside of directives that manipulate the DOM and so on.